# How to use dynamic sql with unknown numbers of parameters getting through an xml?

Tags: xml, oracle, dynamic, parameters, ref-cursor

I still have a problem although I read this forum and many others via google. Maybe someone can give me a hint.
I have to create a procedure in oracle 10g which provides a ref `Cursor` with the results.
This result can be filtered by a parameter, which contains a `String` in xml format.

The structure is

```
 <filter>
    <columnNameToSearch>
       SearchValue
    </columnNameToSearch>
 </filter>
```

Because I don't know which columns will be filtered I concatenated it dynamically as shown below.
But because of the possibility of Sql Injection I would like to parameterize the filter part.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_GET_VALUES(p_recordset OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,    
p_xml    IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT '<filter />')
AS
p_roleId ROLES.ROLE_ID%TYPE;
p_xmlDocument dbms_xmldom.DOMDocument;
p_xmlNode dbms_xmldom.DOMNode;
p_filterNodes dbms_xmldom.DOMNodeList;
p_nodeName          VARCHAR2(50);
p_nodeValue         VARCHAR2(50);
p_filterNodesLength NUMBER;
p_sqlStatement      VARCHAR2(4000);
p_filterStatement   VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
p_xmlDocument := dbms_xmldom.newDOMDocument(XMLTYPE(p_xml));
p_xmlNode     := dbms_xmldom.makeNode(dbms_xmldom.getDocumentElement(p_xmlDocument));
p_filterNodes       := dbms_xmldom.getChildNodes(p_xmlNode);
p_filterNodesLength := DBMS_XMLDOM.getLength(p_filterNodes);
FOR i               IN 0 .. p_filterNodesLength - 1
LOOP
p_xmlNode   := DBMS_XMLDOM.item(p_filterNodes, i);
p_nodeName  := DBMS_XMLDOM.getNodeName(p_xmlNode);
p_nodeValue := DBMS_XMLDOM.getNodeValue(DBMS_XMLDOM.getFirstChild(p_xmlNode));
p_filterStatement := p_filterStatement || ' AND ' || p_nodeName || ' = ' || p_nodeValue;
END LOOP;

p_sqlStatement := 'SELECT firstname, lastname, phone FROM myTable WHERE 1 = 1 ' || p_filterStatement;
OPEN p_recordset FOR p_sqlStatement;
END TEST_GET_VALUES;
```

I tried using the dbms_sql package, but couldn't get it to work.
Maybe someone can provide me an example, or give me hints what to do.

Comment: What is your question? Because it looks like the dynamic SQL and the cursor should work.

Comment: Sorry my laptop broke, so I couldn't get online. My problem here is, that I want to use parameters to avoid sql injection. But the  number of parameters can vary depending on the xml I get.